# How to change the entry file in metro bundler?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

I have a react native application which has multiple entry points . ( This application is integrated into a android project). Now i want to run the metro server (npm run start) in development. Now when i run the metro bundler it always point to index.js file. Now i want to change the metro server path to point to specific entry file so that i can do hot reloading. It would be great if anyone could help me this.